# Visio 2010 64 bit won't run

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-visio-2010

I have recently installed Visio 2010 Premium 64 bit and although it installed fine, when i try to run it i get

**c:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_04480933ab2137b1\mfc90u.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.  Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support**

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the application but it just won't work.  Any clues/suggestions?

Office 2010 which i installed prior is working fine.

Comment: Are you using the Technet or MSDN version of Office 2010?

Comment: action pack version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and its a right pain to do, but this article from MS explains how to replace files in the WinSxS folders.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us